# Selecting from database error mysqli_query / mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli

I'm trying to get this information out of the database:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM station_control WHERE station_no > 0 ORDER BY station_ord";
```

it then says it expects parameters in these two lines:

```
$station_result=  mysqli_query($query);
$num=  mysqli_fetch_array($station_result);
```

this is what I want to output, basically to pull every station name from the database called station_ord and the names are under station_name:

```
$i=0;while ($i < $num) {
   $station_name1=mysqli_result($station_result,$i,"station1_name");
   $station2_name=  mysqli_result($station_result, $i,"station2_name");
   $station3_name=  mysqli_result($station_result, $i,"station3_name");
   $station4_name=  mysqli_result($station_result, $i,"station4_name");
   $station5_name=  mysqli_result($station_result, $i,"station5_name");

   echo "<b>
    $station1_name $station2_name2</b>    <br>
    $station3_name<br>
    $station1_name4_name<br>
    $station5_name<hr>    <br>";

   $i++;
}
```

I haven't put in the station_name yet as im confused to where and how I configure that.
Any ideas how to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you try to do, but try

```
<?php
$station_result=  mysqli_query($query);
$records =  mysqli_fetch_array($station_result);
foreach ($records as $record) :?>
      <b><?php echo $record['station_name']; ?></b><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

ref : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
and http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php for examples

Comment: im trying to pull the names of each station stored in the table into a string of its own

Comment: But do you really have the columns : station1_name, station2_name,.. in your table or you just want the first record of the column station_name, then the second records,... ? If you want the records for the column station_name, both answers here should work...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$station_result=  mysqli_query($query);
$results=  mysqli_fetch_array($station_result);
foreach ($results as $row) {
  // echo whatever you want here
  echo $row['station_name'];
}
```